# How to disable a button until all entries are filled?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm working with xamarin.forms and trying to disable a button until all entries are filled.

I'm working with mvvm pattern and tried to disable it using binding like that:

```cs
    private bool en;
    public bool GetValuesEn
    {
        get
        {
            if (login == "")
            {
                en = false;
                return en;
            } else { en = true; return en; };
        }
    }
    public bool En
    {
        get
        {
            return en;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref en, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GetValuesEn));
        }
    }
```

en is binded to the property is enabled of the button

Comment: Is the button bound to a command?

Comment: as @Nkosi said, if you don't have a command bound to the button, this is not really MVVM. With command, you just set its `CanExecute` to false and the button is disabled

Comment: I'd write a MultiTrigger with Entry Text as inputs with length to boolean converter

Comment: i've solved it thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

you're on the right track

```
public bool IsButtonEnabled
{
  get {
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry1) &&
           !String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry2) &&
           // repeat for all Entries
  }
}
```

however, for this to work, the setters for `entry1`, `entry2`, etc should fire `PropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled");`

Comment: This is a better answer than mine because it doesn't violate MVVM best practice by not letting your code-behind know the ViewModel

Comment: yes thanks for replying , i've tried that but steal have the same problem , now even if i field all entries ,the button is always disabled

Comment: then you need to *debug* the code to figure out why its not working

Comment: it's oook now it's working properly ,thank you so mush for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Set `TextChanged` event to all of your entries in xaml:

```
TextChanged="EntryTextChanged"
```

**Step 2:** Implement `EntryTextChanged` in code-behind:

```
private async void EntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewTextValue != null)
    {
        var entry = sender as Entry;
        ((MyViewModel)entry).IsAllEntriesFilled();
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Implement `IsAllEntriesFilled()` in your ViewModel and check if all binded properties of the Entries have some text:

```
public void IsAllEntriesFilled()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entry1Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entry2Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entry3Text))
    {
        IsButtonEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsButtonEnabled = false;
    }
}
```